# how to use form data saved in an array in another html file

Tags: javascript, html

im having a project in which there is an html file for sign up and another one for login. So i am storing the data from the sign up form in some arrays and i want to use them in the login file but the arrays seems to be empty. Is there somekind of global array in javascript or something like that? Thanks in advance :) My javascript code is:

```
var usernames=[]; //login usernames
var passwords=[]; //login passwords
var personUsr = []; //signup usernames
var personPass = []; //signup passwords

function insert(){ //login onclick function
 var usernameValue = document.getElementById('username').value;
 var passwordValue = document.getElementById('password').value;

 usernames[usernames.length]=usernameValue;
 passwords[passwords.length]=passwordValue;

 document.getElementById('username').value="";
 document.getElementById('password').value="";
 for(var i = 0; i < personUsr.length; i++) {
   if(titleValue===personUsr[i]){
       alert("user found"); }
   else{
       alert("no user with that username");}      
    }
 }


function submitSignUp(){ //signup onclick function

    var firstName = signupform.elements["firstname"].value;
    var lastName = signupform.elements["lastname"].value;
    var country = signupform.elements["countrySel"].selectedIndex.value;
    var user = signupform.elements["username"].value;
    var pass = signupform.elements["password"].value;
    var repass = signupform.elements["password2"].value;

    personUsr[personUsr.length]=user;
    personPass[personPass.length]=pass;         
 }
```

Comment: you need to store this data somewhere!! you cannot post or send JavaScript data from one file to other (not unless you are using ajax). JavaScript is always specific to your current page!

Comment: so only obvious solution is ajax? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is built for this purpose. If you want to post javascript variable to other page you should use ajax.

Else you can use a sever-side technique to do this

Comment: My project is only for simulation so i am trying to find an easier way

Comment: how about using cookies?